# Bootstrap 5 - Position Button in Corner

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I have a web page that uses Bootstrap 5 (Beta 1). On this page, I need to add a button to the lower-right corner of the `main` area. In an effort to accomplish this, I attempted to use the [positioning utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/position/) in Bootstrap 5. My current code looks like this:

```
<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Pictures</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main role="main" class="flex-fill" style="background-color:pink;">
    <div>
      <div class="container">Here</div>
      <div class="position-relative">
        <div class="position-absolute bottom-0 end-0">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Add Picture</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer class="footer mt-auto bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      Hello
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get the "Add Picture" button positioned in the lower-right corner of the `main` element, just above the footer. I've tried several combinations of the positioning utilities. However, I can't seem to get it working properly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

```
<div class="container">Here</div>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-end justify-content-end">
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Add Picture</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Plus remove class from main